# Bundling ecmascript 6 modules into a single file?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, build, module, bundle

is it possible to bundle modules to a single minified .js to include in a single  tag ? I know it's a different story with server-side js packages, but in my case, it's really intended to be loaded by a browser and I don't want to have multiple http requests.

Here is an over-simplified example, of sub-trees / namespaces that aren't necessarily related together, but ultimately grouped together in a single object:

```
// fruits/base.js
    export default class Fruit_base {};

// fruits/apple.js
    import Fruit_base from "./base.js";
    export default class Apple extends Fruit_base {};

// fruits/orange.js
    import Fruit_base from "./base.js";
    export default class Orange extends Fruit_base {};

// fruits/allOfThem.js
    import Fruit_base from "./base.js";
    import Apple from "./apple.js";
    import Orange from "./orange.js";
    const Fruits = {Fruit_base, Apple, Orange};
    export default Fruits;



// animals/base.js
    export default class Animal_base {};

// animals/cat.js
    import Animal_base from "./base.js";
    export default class Cat extends Animal_base {};

// animals/dog.js
    import Animal_base from "./base.js";
    export default class Dog extends Animal_base {};

// animals/allOfThem.js
    import Animal_base from "./base.js";
    import Cat from "./cat.js";
    import Dog from "./dog.js";
    const Animals = {Animal_base, Cat, Dog};
    export default Animals;


// main.js
    import Fruits from "./fruits/allOfThem.js";
    import Animals from "./animals/allOfThem.js";
    const someVar = 1;
    const someOtherVar = 2;
    function someFunc() {}
    const Things = {Fruits, Animals, someVar, someOtherVar, someFunc};
    export default Things;
```

And then be able to do the following :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="module">
            import Things from "/assets/js/things.min.js";

            const apple = new Things.Fruits.Apple();
            const dog = new Things.Animals.Dog();
            Things.someFunc();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What confuses me, is that in importing / exporting modules, we can use aliases, so I'm not sure how any tool could figure out the appropriate names required for that to work.

Also, if it was for server-side js, [from what I read](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-modules-part-2-module-bundling-5020383cf306/), I know some bundlers do tree shaking in order to only deploy the minimum, but in my case, everything has to be included, as we don't know what the browser will do with it (for example, play with it in the console)

thanks for your help !

Comment: You're looking for a bundler like Webpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to bundle modules to a single minified .js to include in a single tag ?

Yes, this is one of the things bundlers like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and [Rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org) do.

> I know some bundlers do tree shaking in order to only deploy the minimum, but in my case, everything has to be included, as we don't know what the browser will do with it (for example, play with it in the console)

You can turn tree-shaking off. It can be non-obvious, but for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51051397/157247) shows how to turn it off in Webpack 4. It's more straight-forward with Rollup: [There's an option](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#treeshake).

---

That said, if playing with things from the console is an expected use-case, modules may not be the best choice, since they encapsulate their contents rather than dumping everything into global scope.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried with rollup, using:
    rollup main.js --file bundle.js --format iife
but I got an error like:
    F:\Proj 2020\Code\import-test\public\tests\rollup>rollup main.js --file bundle.js --format iife
    F:\lcm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\loadConfigFile.js:484
            ? (await import(url.pathToFileURL(fileName).href)).default
                     ^^^^^^
    
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
        at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)...

Comment: @MB101874 - That looks like an unrelated problem, trying to use `import` in a non-module.